# Does it make sense for me to say "plentiful body"?

Tags: descriptive-grammar

I want to say ***"the beast is going to feast on his plentiful body"***. Does that make sense or what should I say instead?

Comment: Presuming you mean that there's a lot of body there to feast on, how about *bountiful*?

Comment: Could you also give some context? What are you trying to say? Is the beast talking about its own body?

Comment: The problem with plentiful is it means *existing in or yielding great quantities* – there are lots of something. There's only one body, so it wouldn't seem to fit. Perhaps *expansive*?